# Passwords Generator, problem writing it to a file

Tags: python-3.x, file

i was doing a password generator. And i wanted to write all the passwords to a file. But it only write one line, even though i used the method `.writelines()`.

Python File:

```
import random

lower = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"
upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
num = "0123456789"
lenght = 24

all = lower+upper+num

pwd = "".join(random.sample(all,lenght))
for i in range(0,100):
    with open("pwd.txt","w+") as f:
        f.writelines(pwd)
```

pwd.txt:

```
WQaTfK4R3crgZV5XE16Yyoik
```

Comment: You're opening the file for writing each time and overwriting with only the last password. You can open the file for writing before the loop to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To generate 100 **different** passwords and add them to the file pwd.txt, I made a few changes to your code. I put the variable pwd inside your for loop, to generate 100 different passwords. Then, to avoid redefining the variable f 100 times, I put that before the for loop. Also, when writing to the file, I included a newline, so that each password would be written to a new line. Here is the resulting code I produced. Tell me if you need anything else.

```
import random

lower = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"
upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
num = "0123456789"
length = 24

all = lower+upper+num


with open("pwd.txt", "w+") as f:
    for i in range(0, 100):
        pwd = "".join(random.sample(all, length))
        f.write(pwd + "\n")
f.close()
```

If you were trying to rewrite the **same** password 100 times to the file pwd.txt, my answer needs some editing. I wasn't sure if that was actually what you wanted. If that case, here would be the edited code:

```
import random

lower = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"
upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
num = "0123456789"
length = 24

all = lower+upper+num
pwd = "".join(random.sample(all, length))

with open("pwd.txt", "w+") as f:
    for i in range(0, 100):
        f.write(pwd + "\n")
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to use string module to get the ascii letters and numbers, using `string.ascii_letters` and `string.digits`.

This way you'd get a function `get_pass`, like so:

```py
import string
import random


def get_pass(length):
    return ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, length))
```

Then, as you're not actually writing a ton of data, but a small set, you can use a list comprehension and use writelines() over it, just two lines of code.

Be careful, as this pre-loads all the passwords in memory before writing the file, so if you use it for a huge number of passwords it'll lead to memory usage issues.

```py
with open('pwd.txt', 'w') as fop:
    fop.writelines([f'{p}\n' for p in (get_pass(24) for _ in range(100))])
```

And you'll end up with a file like:

```
uDBN1Xr7bF6TJa4dsypZw8lC
xLeOJQZWpC1h42RI6BSnq0zK
LqzuhVoCEi1BWJvSd0DOcAMQ
wUyurf150BldE3ibCJMSa8jP
BmGI0qobunfk59PVxMYazAip
qozsIwCH3rmgBRyDQJ5W7APE
QAPe0fwkj4RmagTd6ctzMsYy
wAZ9Q8WLvI7deDgSa4YryslB
mM8seBJWiTAxh5nqKbLkj1vU
SB8JeA45H10UD9u7k6zjKvyc
7GnWQ5SvNgADclRB42tqUmhZ
... up until 100 lines
```